# how to sort the dataset based on the same certain column values in R

Tags: r

My dataset looks like below

| Parameter | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | 1 | 12 |
| Y | 1 | 14 |
| Z | 1 | 15 |
| X | 2 | 10 |
| Y | 2 | 09 |
| Z | 2 | 22 |
| X | 3 | 08 |
| Y | 3 | 07 |
| Z | 3 | 20 |

as you can see, we have similar values in column "Parameter" and "Date", I want to convert the rows to column to re-order the data set based on the same values of "Parameter" and "Date".

my expected result is like

| Date | X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | 14 | 15 |
| 2 | 10 | 09 | 22 |
| 3 | 08 | 07 | 20 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for pivoting your data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% pivot_wider(Date, names_from = Parameter, values_from = Value)
# A tibble: 3 × 4
   Date X     Y     Z    
  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     1 12    14    15   
2     2 10    09    22   
3     3 08    07    20
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is turning turning long data to wide data and there are many answers to that. Many prefer the `pivot_wider` function in the `tidyr` package.

Package `data.table` has `melt` and `dcast`: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reshape.html

Or you could use the `reshape2` package: https://github.com/hadley/reshape

The R inbuild function `reshape` is somewhat cumbersome to use and I do not recommend it.